# Run a Jenkins pipeline but modify the code before the pipeline runs

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have some code in a subfolder of a repo that is used as a source template for new repositories that themselves have their own full CI/CD pipeline and can be deployed to a server and handle work.

It would be very valuable to get some additional automated testing done by running the source template repo's Jenkins build/deployment pipeline (as captured in a Jenkinsfile) against that subfolder without first having created a new repo from it. The only catch is, there are some template placeholders that must have values injected before build/deployment will work.

Ideally, the best scenario is to use the exact Jenkinsfile pipeline script from the template folder. However, creating a Jenkins pipeline job naively pointing to that Jenkinsfile doesn't seem like it will work because:

1. The Jenkinsfile won't know to perform the build against the subfolder instead of the root, and the Jenkinsfile really shouldn't change—it has to work when the code is running in its own new, templatized, repo.
2. The templatizing hasn't been performed yet, so the template folder can't actually be built and deployed without a little modification because the values will be incorrect or invalid.

I've spent some time trying to figure out how to achieve this and have been unsuccessful so far. Here's what I've tried or researched/thought about:

- Split the template Jenkinsfile into two parts, `the pipeline {}` portion and the `steps {}` portion, then create a new pipeline job with a custom Jenkinsfile that attempts to load the steps file. This didn't work, because you can't call a step from within a step, and you can't run any script that would run another groovy file (that I was able to figure out) outside of a step. This wouldn't be perfect, because then the templated app would have its Jenkinsfile split into two pieces, and the test scenario wouldn't be using the *exact* same pipeline script, but it would be valuable.
- Create a freestyle project that does an SCM checkout, makes all the modifications locally that are needed (quickly simulating the full templatizing process without having to create a new repository), changes to the template sub-folder (and possibly modify the workdir or move files around/delete them as needed so the templatized app is in the root) and then kicks off the existing Jenkinsfile pipeline script that should work from there. I tried this, but can't figure out how to kick off a pipeline job directly from a freestyle project.
- Make a freestyle project that does the same process as above, then saves artifacts, then create *another* pipeline job that uses those artifacts as its build source. But I'm not even sure if this is possible and I've spent too much research time on this already.
- Perform the quick templatizing process, and on each build create a new branch (named with the build number perhaps) in some repository for this purpose, then kick of a downstream pipeline job that uses that branch as its source. This could work, but brings in a bunch of added complexity and an outside dependency on a repo which would then have a bunch of branches needing cleanup, requiring another job that may not always run successfully, itself. It would be really nice to not have to do this.
- Duplicate the template's Jenkinsfile another location of the parent repo, and automatically add the required steps to templatize it and use the subfolder. However, this is far from ideal because then we're using code to write code in a custom way (huge source for bugs/breakage), and also, almost the same code has to be in two places and differences could creep in between the two Jenkinsfiles that are supposed to be identical in most parts.
- In some developer-side pro-processing build process, fetch the template's Jenkinsfile, inject the subfolder and templatizing changes, and save a copy of it in a different location, to be committed with any other changes. NOT ideal. Generated files shouldn't be committed, and this creates a burden on developers and may be hard to enforce—seems brittle and not a good strategy for actually preventing differences creeping in between the two Jenkinsfiles. Still the same problem about code writing code.
- Add automated commits to the parent repo that update the Jenkinsfile copy instead of making the developer do it. While changes to the Jenkinsfile aren't frequent, such extra commits are ugly, and this has many of the same problems as listed in previous ideas.

That's it—for now I'm out of ideas.

Any advice on how to achieve what I'm looking for without a lot of extra complexity or work?

*Background: right now, we don't have any automated tests against certain portions of the template, since a full test of all parts requires not just building or running unit tests but actually deploying the (templated) application to a server to test the deployment code itself, plus running end-to-end tests against a successfully-deployed result. Ideally, the long term solution is actually to run the new-repo creation process and then perform tests from there, but that will involve a lot of time and work get fully automated creation/templatizing, testing, and tear-down going. Plus, it will be necessary to make the template-source repo wait for all that testing to complete before its own test process can be marked as successful. So, a quick solution that gets most of the value by simply deploying the app as-is from its subfolder (with minor templatizing done) would be really awesome. Long term we're moving away from Jenkins, but need this testing now!*